# Is it possible to read all database operations from Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

If I have a database set up as such:

```
@Apples = new Meteor.Collection 'apples'
```

Is there a way to set up a function to be called every time a database operation is made on apples? E.g.

```
Apple.update {name: 'Frank'}
```

leads to something like this being called:

```
appleOperation = (operation, parameter) ->
    # Log the operation in another database
    # Continue with the database operation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for *cursor*.observe and/or *cursor*.observeChanges. Excuse me for not using Coffeescript

```
Apples = new Meteor.Collection("apples");

Apples.find().observe({
    added: function(document) {
        // Do stuff with the added document
    },
    changed: function(newDoc, oldDoc) {
        // Do stuff with the old and new document
    },
    removed: function(document) {
        // Do stuff with the removed document
    }
});
```

If you now add a document:

```
Apples.insert({name: "Frank"});
```

the added-function will be called with whatever ID Frank was inserted with, and {name: "Frank"} as the fields-parameter.

Similar with observeChanges, which only gives you the changed fields

```
Apples.find().observeChanges({
    added: function(id, fields) {
        // Do stuff with the added document
    },
    changed: function(id, fields) {
        // Do stuff with the changed fields
    },
    removed: function(id) {
        // Do stuff with the id of the removed document
    }
});
```

See the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, and there's a nice package to handle all the nitty gritty too:

https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks